# Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Cannot read, unknown typeId: 34. Did you forget to register an adapter ? ( Flutter )

Tags: android, ios, flutter, hive, adapter

App is not restarting after writes made using hive in disk. It's throwing the above error and app is not opening.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is place registerAdapter above Hive.openBox

```
await Hive.initFlutter();
Hive.registerAdapter(TodoAdapter());
await Hive.openBox('todos');
```